# SQL - WHERE clause based on an average?

Tags: mysql

In my SQL final exam, there was a question to the effect of:

> Display the customer ID, the number of times the customer has placed an order, and the average shipping amount the customer has paid rounded to two decimal places. Only display results where the average shipping is greater than $5.

My answer:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, 
    COUNT(o.order_id) AS 'number_of_orders',
    ROUND(AVG(o.ship_amount), 2) AS 'ave_shipping_amount'
FROM customers c JOIN orders o
    ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY c.customer_id;
```

I attempted `WHERE ave_shipping_amount > 5` above the `GROUP BY`, but this didn't work as the ave_shipping_amount column doesn't exist.
I also tried `WHERE ROUND(AVG(o.ship_amount), 2) > 5`, but this was an incorrect use of a group function.

How would this question be solved? It seems basic enough, but I'm going insane trying to figure it out.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: Excellent first question here! It's a very well-stated problem, includes the relevant information, and clearly shows your effort to figure things out yourself before posting. I wish more new users made this sort of effort. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use HAVING:

```
HAVING ROUND(AVG(o.ship_amount), 2) > 5
```

It is like a WHERE clause except that it gets computed after aggregates

Comment: How did I go through an entire SQL course without knowing this... Anyway, it's perfect, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. It is one of those parts of SQL that isn't used super-often but is invaluable when you need it!